# Can a muslim work to a boss of other religion and / or with bad behavior?

Tags: practical-islam

If a muslim is hired to work for a company, but this company have practices from other religions - such as, celebrate the New Year of Common Era or Christmas -, what should he does? He must change his job / quit his work or he can take part on this occasions?
And if my boss have a behavior like drinking alcohol, dating married women, applying interest in his accounts, should I accept orders from him?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, if your boss is not asking you to commit unlawful (haraam) and respects your religious duties, you can work under him. Also, if you pray for him, it would be really beneficial.